# geom_line groups and scale_color_manual Produce Unexpected Error

Tags: r, ggplot2

Oddly enough, I can't find anything online to solve this problem I'm having.

Generating data:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(ggplot2)
X <- as.numeric(1:100)
df <- data.frame(x=X,y=rnorm(n=100,sd=.1)+sin(X*pi/200),gp=1)
for (i in 2:4) df <- rbind(df,data.frame(x=X,y=rnorm(n = 100,sd = .1)+sin(X*i*pi/200),gp=i))
```

The head of this data frame looks like:

```
  x            y gp
1 1  0.030678982  1
2 2  0.108093934  1
3 3  0.067512201  1
4 4  0.186648638  1
5 5  0.109397764  1
6 6 -0.005158247  1
```

Sanity check:

```
> unique(df$gp)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Now, all I want to do is plot these 4 lines with various *contrasting* colors; i.e., I do not want the following:

```
> p <- ggplot(data = df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=gp,color=gp))+geom_line()+theme_bw()
> p
```

[image: Bad Contrast Between Lines]

In the above plot, the legend is horrendous and the lines have horrible contrast. Why is this so hard? So I tried the following:

```
> p <- ggplot(data = df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=gp,color=gp))+geom_line()+theme_bw()+scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue','green','black'))
> p
```

which yields:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

How can I tell ggplot to just give me a wide variety of colors and apply them to every line (labeled by `group=gp`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grouping variable ("gp") is of class numeric, so ggplot2 is having a difficult time assigning a discrete set of values to a continuous variable. If you reassign "gp" as a character or factor, you can manually adjust the colors as you're doing above.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(ggplot2)
X <- as.numeric(1:100)
df <- data.frame(x=X,y=rnorm(n=100,sd=.1)+sin(X*pi/200),gp=1)
for (i in 2:4) df <- rbind(df,data.frame(x=X,y=rnorm(n = 100,sd = .1)+sin(X*i*pi/200),gp=i))

### Classify as character ###
df$gp <- as.character(df$gp)

### Plot ###
p <- ggplot(data = df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=gp,color=gp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
plot(p)
```

[image]

```
### Manually adjust discrete colors ###
p <- p + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "black"))
plot(p)
```

[image]

If you wanted to leave your grouping variable "gp" in numeric, then you could use 'scale_colour_gradient' instead and specify the bookends of the colors to scale your lines.

```
### Reclassify as numeric ###
df$gp <- as.numeric(df$gp)

### Plot ###
p <- ggplot(data = df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=gp,color=gp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue")
plot(p)
```

[image]